# How can a root user open an app as login user in mac OSX programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

This is my code

```
NSString *script = @"su \"username\" <<EOF_OPEN\n"
                   "\"path_to_target_app_exe\"\n"
                   "EOF_OPEN";
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:@[@"-c", script]];
[task launch];
```

The app process belongs to current login user, and the problem is that there are 3 parent procs(bash->su->zsh->target_app), I can not handle with these parent procs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *script = @"su \"username\" <<EOF_OPEN\n"
                   "open \"path_to_target_app\"\n"
                   "EOF_OPEN";
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:@[@"-c", script]];
[task launch];
```

above is the solution, using

> open xxx.app

instead of

> xxx.app/Contents/Macos/xxx